# regExp mongoose - Object #<Object> has no method 'test'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sails.js

I'm trying to run a mongoose document.save but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'test'
    at model.matchValidator (C:\wamp\www\Ayolan-Translation\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\string.js:221:16)
    at SchemaType.doValidate (C:\wamp\www\Ayolan-Translation\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:627:28)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (C:\wamp\www\Ayolan-Translation\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:614:19)
    at Document.validate.err (C:\wamp\www\Ayolan-Translation\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:956:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

I'm using sails framework, but I run this with a migration module that doesn't run sails, so basically I just call my own bootstrap (equivalent to app.js but don't start the entire framework, just my own code).

The problem is, when I try to make a document.save inside one of my migration script, I got the previous error, its because of the following code:

**mongoose/lib/schema/string.js**

```
SchemaString.prototype.match = function match (regExp, message) {
  // yes, we allow multiple match validators

  var msg = message || errorMessages.String.match;

  function matchValidator (v){
    return null != v && '' !== v
      ? regExp.test(v)
      : true
  }

  this.validators.push([matchValidator, msg, 'regexp']);
  return this;
};
```

When I take a look at regExp, it's an object with only a **proto**, nothing more.
I don't know where is the problem, it works correctly when I run my app normally, any idea?

Comment: But, this code is from mongoose, I can't modify it. I mean, it should work by itself!

Comment: I also tried to import manually my Schema and create models but same error.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your schema definition and the code that calls `save`?

Comment: I'm afraid that question is from a year ago and that code doesn't exist anymore. Gonna close it.

Comment: OK, probably best to just delete it then.